# micrometer-tracing not working in spring boot 3 JMS listener application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, micrometer-tracing

I have a spring boot application which uses Spring Boot 3, micro-meter tracing dependency. it is a JMS listener application.it is used to log trace and span id before the migration when it used to use sleuth.

I tried to create EnvironmentPostProcessor to force the logging pattern but it did not help

Comment: JMS doesn't have, yet, out-of-the-box trace/span id propagation with Spring 6. That is coming with Spring 6.1. So you will need to write an interceptor of sorts to accomplish this for the time being.